# Autosuggest react.js component won't update input style on render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using the [react-autosuggest component](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) and I'm styling the border of input part of it with a react inline style which changes based on user input. However, despite the new style being passed to the Autosuggest component every time `render()` is called, it's not updated. Here's what I have:

```js
var borderStyle;
        if (gradient) {
            borderStyle = {
                borderImageSlice: 1,
                borderImage: '-webkit-linear-gradient(right, '+borderColour2+' 0%, '+borderColour2+' 40%, '+borderColour1+' 60%, '+borderColour1+' 100%) 1'
            };   
        }
        else {             
            borderStyle = {
                'borderColor': borderColour1
            };   
        }
        var theme = {
            container: 'react-autosuggest__container',
            containerOpen: 'react-autosuggest__container--open',
            input: borderStyle,
            suggestionsContainer: 'react-autosuggest__suggestions-container',
            suggestion: 'react-autosuggest__suggestion',
            suggestionFocused: 'react-autosuggest__suggestion--focused',
            sectionContainer: 'react-autosuggest__section-container',
            sectionTitle: 'react-autosuggest__section-title',
            sectionSuggestionsContainer: 'react-autosuggest__section-suggestions-container'
        };
<Autosuggest suggestions={suggestions}
    theme={theme}
    onSuggestionsUpdateRequested={this.onSuggestionsUpdateRequested}
    getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
    renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
    inputProps={inputProps}
    ref={this.saveInput}
    onSuggestionSelected={this.selectCard} />
```

I'm using default values for everything but input. I know the styling works because I gave it a hardcoded gradient and on first page load it displays it just as I want. I also know the value of 'borderstyle' is correct and updated when it's passed into `theme`, and therefore when `theme` is passed into the component to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in version 3.5.1.